# Is my mathematical formulation correct?

Tags: functions, graph-theory

I have an input graph as below.

[image: Input graph]

I am trying to represent the above pictorial representation in mathematical terms.

> The above pictorial representation can be viewed as a function from X
>   to P (Y), where P (Y) represents the powerset of Y.  P (Y) represents
>   the set of all subsets of Y.

Is my above mathematical formulation correct for the given picture?

Comment: What do $Ai$ and $Li$ represent for $i \in { 1,2,3,4,5}$

Comment: They represent 2 domains (The set X on the left side represents data from source A and the set Y on the right side represents data from source B). They are connected using the edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is correct.

Denote the function as $f$.

Then,for example: $$f(A_{1})=\{L_{1},L_{2}\}
,f(A_{5})=\emptyset$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Should I modify anything in my wordings to represent the problem in mathematical terms?

Comment: @Ramesh - I don't think you do. But you might want to add the comment that $A_5$ is being mapped to the empty set. I admit that at first I didn't realize it